# Rails 3.1 assets: Calling image_url in scss raises Unrecognized file type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

When I call `image_url('path/to/image.png')` in my `css.scss` file, I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Unrecognized file type: png)
  (in /home/ramon/source/unstilted/app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css.scss)):
    ...
  app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css.scss:134
  app/views/layouts/site_admin.html.haml:8:in `_app_views_layouts_site_admin_html_haml__354054488_99259250'
```

I'm using `compass '0.12.0.alpha.0'` from the `rails_31` branch. Not sure if that's the issue. But I thought it was worth mentioning.

How do I include images in a `css.scss` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was something that wasn't working properly in that version of compass that I was using. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/compass-users/1HLgiPeqLYE/YCRU631vjHMJ) for details.

Answer (score 4):

actually, using `background: image-url('name-of-image.png')` seems to work just fine. (Note the hyphen instead of an underscore).

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the file `admin.css.scss.erb`.

Then you can use view helpers in your css.

```
background-image: url(<%= image_url('foo.jpg') %>)
```

Not pretty, does the job.